# How to automate TextBox control for Enter key

Tags: vb.net

I have to do the following for each textbox control.

```
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
     Me.DateDateTimePicker.Focus()
 End If
```

Should there be a For Next loop option, pls mention under which Sub Routine I should code the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're saying, I think this should be placed within the KeyPressed event within the text box you are trying to run this piece of code from. You can also integrate multiple events  for many controls into a single method.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can but your code inside a 'KeyUp' event and then alter the 'KeyUp' event of one textbox to handle more than one textbox keyups event, but only one code can be executed for all of them,
check this:

```
Private Sub ***TextBox1_KeyUp***(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
    Handles TextBox1.KeyUp, ***TextBox2.KeyUp***, ***TextBox3.KeyUp***

        '*************
        'Write your code Here
        '*************
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you can use only one method to handle multiple events.

Moreover, you can execute sender-customized code:

```
Sub MyEventHandler(sender as Object, e as Event) Handles obj.ev, obj2.ev, obj3.ev

    'Use sender property (properly casted, if necessary) 
    'to run sender specific code

    DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text = "foo"

End Sub
```